# CloudFlare error 1010: banned access based on your browser's signature

Tags: support, google-chrome, cloudflare

A new "error" for me: whenever I attempt to visit SO or any given question, CloudFlare seems to intercept Windows 7 x64, Chrome 44's request and throw up an error page:

> ## Error 1010
>
> Ray ID: 20e2ca08........ • 2015-07-30 17:30:02 UTC
>
> ### Access denied
>
> #### What happened?
>
> The owner of this website (stackoverflow.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (20e2ca08........-mh5).

I can visit other pages on the SE network, also MSO, alas just not https://stackoverflow.com/ Do I have some sort of compromised browser?

---

Reading up a little on the error and headers, yadda, yadda, it may be because I have the Referrer Control plugin. I've been using it to shut up the "Did you know you can vote!" popup that happens when I click a Google result. After temporarily disabling it, SO started working, but when I re-enabled it I couldn't replicate the error, so I'm not 100% sure that's it.

Comment: I passed this post along to the SRE team and they'll see if they can reproduce the error/weigh the pros and cons here.

Comment: SE doesn't use CloudFlare for much anymore, so this isn't particularly relevant.

Answer (score 11):

[This is what CloudFlare is saying about the error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171806-Error-1010-The-owner-of-this-website-has-banned-your-access-based-on-your-browser-s-signature)

> The 1010 error message states that the domain owner is blocking this
>   request based on your web browser's signature.
>
> If you are the site owner:
>
> A website admin can turn this feature off by doing the following:
>   Settings->CloudFlare Settings->Browser Integrity Check->Toggle Off.
>
> If you are a site visitor:
>
> A firewall, proxy, a browser plugin or extension may be throwing a
>   false positive. Try visiting the site with a different browser as an
>   alternative way of accessing the site.

[On another page they're explaining the Browser Integrity Check with a bit more detail](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-What-does-the-Browser-Integrity-Check-do-):

> CloudFlare's Browser Integrity Check is similar to Bad Behavior and
>   looks for common HTTP headers abused most commonly by spammers and
>   denies access to your page.  It will also challenge visitors that do
>   not have a user agent or a non standard user agent (also commonly used
>   by abuse bots, crawlers or visitors).

There are a few hints here on what the trigger could be, so you might want to check your browser settings or add-ons. Or SE could disable this feature if the harm outweighs the benefit.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the case that you cannot load analytics the problem may not actually be browser settings. Checkout **https://www.cloudflarestatus.com** in case CloudFlare are having system/network issues.

Comment: I'm not sure where you read that analytics could not  be loaded or how that is related to what the OP describes. The rest of your answer could fit as a comment. I doubt overall if this a very useful answer in its current form.

Comment: @rene I disagree. My answer reads ..."problem may not actually be browser settings"... which means it's not always the case. I have experienced it numerously, where the analytics page (https://www.cloudflare.com/a/analytics/mysite/) shows a red alert at the bottom of the page and hence empty readings... and specifically the 1010 error message. Hardly ever I'd use anything but the standard browsers with standard settings. It turns out to be CloudFlare outage as confirmed by https://www.cloudflarestatus.com. The error goes away in a few hours, all on its own.